# Is it possible to have different URLs for edit and view of the same Google Drive folder?

Tags: google-drive, permissions, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder, google-drive-folder

I'd like to share the same Google Drive folder with a group of people and within that group, some have edit access.

However, when I share that link to the folder to view, if I go back to that folder to generate a new separate different edit link for that same folder, it looks like I am getting the same URL link for view only, with a checkbox offered to make it edit for that link. But I don't want everyone to be able to edit it.

Therefore, is it possible to generate 2 different URLs to the same Google Drive folder where 1 of the URLs is for view only and the other is for view AND edit? Only those select people in the group would know the URL for the view and edit.

I already know that I can invite people to have edit permissions for the folder, but that means asking them to provide their Gmail address or Google Account, which can take time for them to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. This should be resolved by generating a view-only link and then adding your people in the list where you assign them with edit access (not necessarily for all of them). In order to speed up things, you could create a proxy account with edit access and send login credentials to your chosen people.

[image: 0]

Comment: +1 thank you. Accepted answer.

Comment: I think this is a good answer because it correctly states that people who need to have edit access need their e-mails added to the list in sharing settings. However, it is terrible advice to say the user should create a new e-mail address just for the purposes of sharing their document! Imagine if the user wants to share a hundred documents this way - it just isn't how Google Drive is supposed to be used. It actually makes it _more_ complicated, because now the receiver has to remember the new e-mail account details as well as their own.

Answer (score -1):

Create a folder(Let's say "Main"). Then move the folder which you want to share(Let's say "Sub") to "Main".

Finally "Sub" is inside the "Main"

Share edit access link of "Main" to the people who you want to give edit access.

Share view access link of the "Sub" to the people who you want to view only
(Confirm that it has only view access using incognito mode)